# Split on semicolon in between alphanumeric characters

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say we have these strings:

```
1. "a;b;c;d;e"
2. "1;2;3;4;5"
3. "!@#$%^&*()_+;!@#$%^&*()_+;"
```

Is there a way so that when calling `.split(';')` it will only split when `;` is between alphanumeric characters?

Expected result:

```
1. a, b, c, d, e
2. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
3. !@#$%^&*()_+;!@#$%^&*()_+; // kept as is
```

This is what I have so far but it doesn't split quite right on where I "expect" it to work.

```
.split(/[A-Za-z0-9];[A-Za-z0-9]/g);
```

Current result:

```
1. (3) ["", ";", ";e"] // no
2. (3) ["", ";", ";5"] // no
3. ["!@#$%^&*()_+;!@#$%^&*()_+;"] // yes
```

---

**Just to update**. This is not an array of string. Above strings are just sample. Also to clarify regarding what I expect to happen.

**The semicolon must be preceded and proceeded by a number or a letter.**

```
Yes - both characters beside the ; must be a letter or a number
a;b > a, b
1;2 > 1, 2
c;3 > c, 3
4;d > 4, d
5;6;a; > 5, 6, a 

No - when either of the characters beside the ; is not a letter or a number
!;@
12$;525
aa;!$242
bbbbbb;
```

---

**Another update** The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48274680/4620773) by [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava) works like a charm but I'm facing some issues in this particular string.

`TestTEST!@#$%^&*()_+{}|\":?><,./;'[]\\=-this is a long text.test 123455899949949494949499499;TestTEST!@#$%^&*()_+{}|\":?><,./‌​;'[]\\=-this is a long text.test 123455899949949494949499499`

His answer was `/([A-Za-z0-9]+);(?=[A-Za-z0-9])/`. But using the said regex to the string above will result to

```
(3) 
"TestTEST!@#$%^&*()_+{}|":?><,./;'[]\=-this is a long text.test ",
"123455899949949494949499499",
"TestTEST!@#$%^&*()_+{}|":?><,./;'[]\=-this is a long text.test 123455899949949494949499499"
```

When the expected is

```
"TestTEST!@#$%^&*()_+{}|\":?><,./;'[]\\=-this is a long text.test 123455899949949494949499499"
"TestTEST!@#$%^&*()_+{}|\":?><,./‌​;'[]\\=-this is a long text.test 123455899949949494949499499"
```

Comment: which one is the `alphanumeric` string

Comment: `alphanumeric` means either a number or a letter, right? so items 1 and 2

Comment: `alphanumeric` according to google is `consisting of or using both letters and numerals.` , but i do not see any such string here, it has either letter or number

Comment: Just use a for loop, I'm writing the answer now. Actually, no I'm not, hafiz answer is perfect, uses a regex

Comment: I grew up calling a character if either a letter or a number as `alphanumeric`. Like this [guy](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/108313/180326). I hope my examples are clear though.

Answer (score 3):

You can use positive and negative [lookaheads](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to ensure that the semicolon is preceded and followed by the characters you want. So, this will work:

```js
let t1 = "a;b;c;d;e";
let t2 = "1;2;3;4;5";
let t3 = "!@#$%^&*()_+;!@#$%^&*()_+;";

console.log(t1.split(/(?![A-Za-z0-9]);(?=[A-Za-z0-9])/g)); // a, b, c, d, e
console.log(t2.split(/(?![A-Za-z0-9]);(?=[A-Za-z0-9])/g)); // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
console.log(t3.split(/(?![A-Za-z0-9]);(?=[A-Za-z0-9])/g)); // !@#$%^&*()_+;!@#$%^&*()_+;
```

Currently, your regex matches an alphanumeric character followed by a semicolon and another alphanumeric character.

Comment: `(?![A-Za-z0-9])` has no meaning here because next character is anyway a semi-colon (i.e. a non-alphanumeric). Also this will split `#;1` into `#, 1` though as per the question it should not split.

Comment: As @anubhava stated, it will split the `;` when it's being surrounded by just 1 alphanumeric. Both must be alphanumeric for it to be split.

Comment: I've added some more details to my question

Answer (score 1):

It appears in modern browsers Javascript has started support of lookbehind.

If that's the case then your solution is a simple lookahead and lookbehind regex as this:

```
/(?<=[a-z0-9]);(?=[a-z0-9])/i
```

- `(?<=[a-z0-9])`: Asserts that we have an alphanumeric at previous position
- `(?=[a-z0-9])`: Asserts that we have an alphanumeric at next position

```js
var inputs = [`TestTEST!@#$%^&*()_+{}|\":?><,./;'[]\\=-this is a long text.test 123455899949949494949499488;TestTEST!@#$%^&*()_+{}|\":?><,.;'[]\\=-this is a long text.test 123455899949949494949499499`,
    'a1;b2;c3;d4;e5;', '#;1', 'a;b;c;d;e', '1;2;3;4;5',
    '!@#\$%^&*()_+;!@#\$%^&*()_+;']
    
const re = /(?<=[a-z0-9]);(?=[a-z0-9])/i;

for (var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++)
   console.log(inputs[i].split(re))
```

---

In older browsers however, Javascript didn't support a lookbehind. You can use a capture group instead of lookbehind to capture previous character that must be a alphanumeric and a positive lookahead to asserts that the semicolon is followed by the a alphanumeric character.

You can use:

```
var arr = str.split(/(.*?[a-z0-9]+);(?=[a-z0-9])/i).filter(Boolean)
```

**Code Demo:**

```js
var inputs = [`TestTEST!@#$%^&*()_+{}|\":?><,./;'[]\\=-this is a long text.test 123455899949949494949499488;TestTEST!@#$%^&*()_+{}|\":?><,.;'[]\\=-this is a long text.test 123455899949949494949499499`,
    'a1;b2;c3;d4;e5;', '#;1', 'a;b;c;d;e', '1;2;3;4;5',
    '!@#\$%^&*()_+;!@#\$%^&*()_+;']

var re = /(.*?[a-z0-9]+);(?=[a-z0-9])/i;

for (var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++)
   console.log(inputs[i].split(re).filter(Boolean));
```

Used `filter(Boolean)` to filter out empty results from output array.

Comment: `A1;B2;C3;D4;E5;` becomes `(9) ["A", "1", "B", "2", "C", "3", "D", "4", "E5;"]`

Comment: I just stumbled upon an issue. `TestTEST!@#$%^&*()_+{}|\":?><,./;'[]\\=-this is a long text.test 123455899949949494949499499;TestTEST!@#$%^&*()_+{}|\":?><,./;'[]\\=-this is a long text.test 123455899949949494949499499` becomes `(3) ["TestTEST!@#$%^&*()_+{}|":?><,./;'[]\=-this is a long text.test ", "123455899949949494949499499", "TestTEST!@#$%^&*()_+{}|":?><,./;'[]\=-this is a long text.test 123455899949949494949499499"]`

Comment: The above string should just be split into 2 elements.

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: I am outside now. I will update it sure reaching back in 2 hours.

Answer (score 1):

You'll see I am using a '#' in the first array as the garbage character to test, but should be good for any non alphanumeric character.  I assume by your comments that you want all alphanumeric strings of more than 1 character eliminated, so that's what I tried to do.

```js
var strs = ["a;bbbb;c;dd;#","1;2;33;4;5","!@#$%^&*()_+;!@#$%^&*()_+;"]

    for (var i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {
      var str = strs[i].split(';');
      for (var j=0; j < str.length; j++) {
       var chars = str[j];
         if (chars.match(/[^A-Za-z\d]{2}/g)) {
          console.log('this is our special character string '+strs[i]);
          break;
        }
       
       if (chars.length > 1 ) continue;
       var output = chars.split(/[^\s]([a-zA-Z\d]{1})/);
        for (var e = 0; e < output.length; e++) {
        var value = output[e];

        if (value && value.match(/[A-Za-z\d]/g)) {
             console.log(value); 
        }         
      }
     }
    }
```

Comment: This seems to be promising so far, I will try more combinations for now.

Comment: `12323;` becomes `(3) ["123", "3", ""]`

Comment: `12323;!` becomes `(3) ["123", "3", "!"]`

Comment: this feels really hacky but you can check out above as I edited with something that does seem to work, although you'd have to rebuild your arrays rather than simply split.